# Python requests post clyp.it upload file

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to upload an audio file to the clyp.it web service. The api is described here: http://clyp.it/api . The relevant excerpt:

```
Uploads are done via a multipart/form-data POST. Consider the following form: 
<form action="http://upload.clyp.it/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
    <input type="file" name="audioFile"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send to Clyp"> 
</form> 

It will create a request that looks like this: 
POST http://upload.clyp.it/upload HTTP/1.1 
Host: upload.clyp.it 
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------21632794128452 
Content-Length: 5005 
-----------------------------21632794128452 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audioFile"; filename="MyAudioFile.mp3" 
Content-Type: audio/mpeg 
(Audio file data goes here)
```

I am able to upload the file by creating a html file with the above form block inside. I wish to be able to upload this file via python. I've been trying to do so using the 'requests' module (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

I've tried this:

```
clyp_file_upload_url = 'https://upload.clyp.it/upload'
music_mp3 = open('/home/jinal/Downloads/music.mp3', 'rb')
send_files = {'audioFile':music_mp3}
r = requests.post(clyp_file_upload_url, files=send_files)
print(r.status_code)
```

It returns a generic 500 error. I suspect I am not building the post request correctly. How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Type` for each uploaded file in the `files` dictionary argument to `requests.post()`, i.e.

```
clyp_file_upload_url = 'http://upload.clyp.it/upload'
music_mp3 = open('/home/jinal/Downloads/music.mp3', 'rb')
send_files = {'audioFile': ('music.mp3', music_mp3, 'audio/mpeg')}
r = requests.post(clyp_file_upload_url, files=send_files)
print(r.status_code)

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(r.json())
{u'AudioFileId': u'5jahwd0y',
 u'Description': u'#Me #TestOfMp3File #Other',
 u'Duration': 12.408,
 u'Latitude': None,
 u'Longitude': None,
 u'Message': None,
 u'Mp3Url': u'http://a.clyp.it/5jahwd0y.mp3',
 u'OggUrl': u'http://a.clyp.it/5jahwd0y.ogg',
 u'PlaylistId': u'0kpvbr1j',
 u'PlaylistUploadToken': u'd5ec65e0e197d5fe45e7b18371a2e1f0',
 u'SecureMp3Url': u'https://s3.amazonaws.com/a.clyp.it/5jahwd0y.mp3',
 u'SecureOggUrl': u'https://s3.amazonaws.com/a.clyp.it/5jahwd0y.ogg',
 u'Successful': True,
 u'Title': u'Me - Test of MP3 File',
 u'Url': u'http://clyp.it/5jahwd0y'}
```

- Note that the URI scheme should be `http`, not `https`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some assumption about request format on their side. I would guess error may be caused by lack of filename. Try:

```
send_files = {'audioFile': ('music.mp3', music_mp3)}
```

and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: The filename was necessary, but it needed the content type as well. Thanks for answering.